# Sql select where select from same table not working

Tags: sql, sybase

I am trying to run sql on a sybase database.

First I want to find all users with Sum of cost more than $50. The users can have more than one products so I looking users with only total poduct cost of more than $50.

I think I need 2 select statement and I tried running it but its not working

```
Select usercode, name, dept, product, cost 
from table1 
where usercode = (select usercode 
                  where product = 'Apple' or product = 'orange' 
                  group by usercode 
                  having (sum(cost) > 50) )
```

Anyone can help please?

Comment: A `from` clause would help in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `IN` operator:

```
Select usercode, name, dept 
from table1 
where usercode IN (select usercode
                   from products 
                   where product IN ('Apple', 'Orange')
                   group by usercode 
                   having sum(cost) > 50 )
```

Alternatively you can use a `JOIN`:

```
select t1.usercode, t1.name, t1.dept, t2.sum_of_cost
from table1 as t1
join (select usercode, sum(cost) as sum_of_cost
      from products 
      where product IN ('Apple', 'Orange')
      group by usercode 
      having sum(cost) > 50 
) as t2 on t1.usercode = t2.usercode
```

Please note that these queries examine the cost of *only* `'Apple', 'Orange'` products.

Comment: Yes.. I looking for total cost for only Apple and orange products that usercode have more than $50.. Some users may have more than 1 qty of the product.  I will try the sql and let you know if it's working. Thanks!!                                         select t1.usercode, t1.name, t1.dept, t2.sum_of_cost
from table1 as t1
join (select usercode, sum(cost) as sum_of_cost
      from products 
      where product IN ('Apple', 'Orange')
      group by usercode 
      having sum(cost) > 50 
) as t2 on t1.usercode = t2.usercode

Comment: @Trunks80 Is there a problem with the query posted?

Comment: Got an error - sybase Ase adaptive server finds no legal query plan for this statement. If an abstract plan is forcing the query plan, checks its corresponding to the query